# Can't connect MySQLfrom a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, shell, centos

I need to learn a transactional database, but I can't connect to MySQL:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$link = new mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456789');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I get the output:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysql_connect' not found in /root/test01.php on line 4

What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: excellent news, now you will not be able to use the obsolete mysql_* functions

Answer (score 1):

removing 'new' as below; because mysql_connect is a function.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456789');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: can u help me Python Code sql = `"SELECT (case when user1 = '1' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS IsEmtpy from dt"
sql1= "DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1 = '%i' " %(1)

try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
                if sql == true:
                        cursor.execute(sql1)
                        print "Sucuess"
                else:
                        print "error"`
print "Error"

Comment: im newbie accepted **all answers** written by Mit CPC only and vice versa..chk their accounts..